# height and width problem of images with percentage

Tags: html, css

when i was trying to set the image size i set width and height to 100%

so when i set the width and height of the image to 100% it is not getting the size 100% percent  of the its parent element if the actual size of the image is smaller than the container
when i was setting the max-width of the container as 100vh the image height is overflowing the container because this time the  actual height of the image is more than the container but in the case of the width it is not overflowing

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
div{
    width:100%;
    max-height:100vh;
}

img{
    width: 100%;
    height:100%; 
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500" alt=""></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not a single punctuation...

Comment: please add an image of your output

Comment: please add/paste proper valid url with your code eg(codepen,codesandbox)

Comment: Without knowing what you _actually_ want to achieve, sometimes image size manipulation is easier using [background-image](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
div{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

img{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height:100%; 
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp9637255.jpg" alt=""></div>
```

This one will help..